# Many-to-many relationships: Use arrays or create new table

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, database-design

> Postgresql v. 14

I want to be able to query all genres related to a movie in a efficient and scalable way, I thought of these approaches and need help deciding, if you know a better approach feel free to post it.

**Problem:**
I have 2 tables. 1 is movie that contains information related to a movie and the 2nd table is genre in which it contains a list of genres that  can be added to movies. Each movie can have **0/null or many** genres.

---

**Solution 1:**
Create a new table called movie_genre which references movie_id and genre_id. This will need to be maintained by a trigger to keep it updated once a new movie gets inserted.

*OR*

**Solution 2:**
Create a new column in movie called genres which contain array of integers that are linked with genre ids, then I'll be able to query the genres like so:

```
select genre.* from genre join movie on genre.id = any(movie.genres) where movie.id = 1;
```

Which do you think is a more sensible way of doing it? Would like to hear from you.

Comment: Go for the properly normalized model: solution 1

Comment: You can simply delete the question, but please don't vandalise it

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1. Definitely. RDBMSs work best when the tables are normalized.

Please, don't consider Solution 2 any further. If you do, your co-workers and yourself a year from now will curse your name.

Seriously.

Comment: @Renewablezip: why would you need a trigger? If you create a new movie, you should know to which genres it belongs to, so just insert into both tables in a single transaction. Besides: how would the trigger know to which genre the movie belongs to?

Comment: Annoying to maintain that extra table? Compared to how annoying it will be to search for, let us say, horror movies with an IT theme?  Seriously, almost all SQL-based applications with many-to-many relationships use the extra table, sometimes called a JOIN table.